# Поиск нужного отрывка(ов) из строки по шаблону

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки, поиск

В переменной есть текст - 
`"создаем какую-то таблицу create table ururu ( id integer, name text ); и ещё одну таблицу create table anyanya ( id integer, ch integer, model text ); вот и всё"`
Нужно найти в тексте все create table и их содержимое до ");" скобки с точкой запятой, и перевести это в другую переменную.

Пробовал вот так сделать `"create table(.|\\s)*\)\\;"` но проблема в том что если несколько `create table );`. Если между между ними что то есть, это тоже попадает в конечный текст. 
И как вывести всё найденное?

```
  vhod=textArea1.getText();
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)create table.*?\\);");
  Matcher m = p.matcher(vhod);
  while(m.find()){
    textArea2.setText(m.group());
  }
```

Comment: Напишите, что не получилось. Какое регулярное выражение не сработало?

Comment: пробовал вот так сделать "create table(.|\\s)*\\)\\;";
но проблема в том что если несколько create table ); если между между ними что то есть, это тоже попадает в конечный текст

Comment: Какой кошмар с этим `(.|\\s)*`, никогда не используйте этот "конструкт". Всё проще: `"(?s)create table.*?\\);"`

Comment: Работает  спасибо, тогда вопрос другой. Как в переменную всё найденное засунуть?

Comment: Я добавил ответ. В Java с регулярками на основе `|` надо быть острожнее, так как при обработке больших текстов часто в связи с этим может возникнуть ошибка Stack Overflow. `(.|\n)*`, `(.|\r?\n)*?` и т.д. лучше заменять обычным `.*` / `.*?` и использовать модификатор DOTALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю, что ваше регулярное выражение должно выглядеть так:

```
"(?s)create table.*?\\);"
```

или объявите так

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("create table.*?\\);", Pattern.DOTALL);
```

**Подробности**:

- `(?s)` - модификатор DOTALL, который разрешает точке отлавливать перевод строки
- `create table` - текст `create table`
- `.*?` - 0 и более любых знаков, однако как можно меньше, до первого
- `\);` - текста `);`.

[Демо](http://ideone.com/zSuO22):

```
String s = "создаем какую-то таблицу create table ururu ( id integer, name text ); и ещё одну таблицу create table anyanya ( id integer, ch integer, model text ); вот и всё";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?s)create table.*?\\);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    lst.add(matcher.group(0)); 
} 
System.out.println(lst);
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось) А зачем в group(0) нужен 0?

Comment: Чтобы ясно было, что нам нужно целое совпадение. Если добавите круглые скобки в выражении (захватывающую подмаску), будет доступ к подсовпадениям (тогда нужен будет `group(1)` и т.д.).

Answer (score 0):

У меня получилось такое решение:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*?(create[\\s]+table.*?\\);)", Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

int index = 0;
while (matcher.find(index)) {
     System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
     index = matcher.end(1);
}
```

Comment: А зачем `.*?` в начале? + Это не сработает, если внутри create table есть знаки перевода строки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  потому что он не останавливается на первом совпадении а идет до последнего create table

Comment: *потому что он не останавливается на первом совпадении а идет до последнего create table* неверное утверждение, находится "самое левое" вхождение create table. Т.е. `Pattern.compile(".*?(create table.*?\\);)");` сработает только если нет знаков перевода строки.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  не нужно переубеждать мой компьютер. В вашей голове может так и выходит, но на практике получается совсем наоборот.

Comment: А почему у ТС в регулярке `(.|\\s)*`? Просто так?

Comment: В исходной задаче не было условия о том, что будет перевод строки в середине create table. Так что это замечание не особо то и полезно. Можно еще много каких ситуаций придумать когда пример мой не будет работать.

Comment: перевод строки вполне может быть для этого и делал `(.|\\s)*`

Comment: спасибо за замечания. поправил ответ